# Python C Extension - Any harm in adding Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS around every pure C call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

It's recommended to wrap pure C functions that block on IO, or even pure C functions that spend substantial time in CPU, in `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` blocks.

Is there any harm to wrapping pretty much all pure C functions (with pure C arguments- no Python API objects), regardless of whether it blocks on IO or CPU for a long time, with `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` ?

For example, say you had the following function, where `some_pure_c_non_io_func` spends a small time on a CPU task. Is there any harm in releasing the GIL here?

```
static PyObject Foo_bar(Foo *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &i)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    some_pure_c_non_io_func(i);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure, but from looking at the code it seems there's no harm. Several popular libraries do this for intensive CPU functions, notably Tensorflow and [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/search?q=ImagingSectionEnter)

`Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` expands to

```c
PyThreadState *_save;
_save = PyEval_SaveThread();
```

`PyEval_SaveThread` saves the current thread state in `_save` (with [`_PyThreadState_Swap](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/048a35659aa8074afe7d7d054e7cea1f8ee6d366/Python/pystate.c#L1002)) and gives up the GIL

Then Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS expands to

```c
PyEval_RestoreThread(_save);
```

which [does the same thing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80449f243b13311d660eab3a751648029bcdd833/Python/ceval.c#L526) in reverse (takes GIL and makes `_save` the current thread state).

Comment: "Several popular libraries do this for intensive CPU functions" isn't really what the question was asking. We know it's worthwhile for CPU intensive functions, but the question is asking about functions that _aren't_ CPU intensive and/or _don't_ do IO? I.e. how quick does a function have to be before you lose time with these calls?